# Selecting first instance of an element with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some markup that looks like this:

```
<section id="accreditation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row-accreditation">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row-accreditation">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I select the `img` in the first `.row-accreditation` div? I've tried using first-of-type and first-child selectors but both do the same thing which is selecting *both* of the images. I also tried to recreate the accepted answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) like so...

```
#accreditation div.row accreditation > img ~ img {blah}
```

...but without success.

Is this possible with css, and if so what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It does work this way in your particular example:

```
.row-accreditation:nth-child(2) > div > img { 
  ...
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzWwxK

But I don't know if the HTML structure will stay the same in your application.